# Pressing enter in a html input box and following a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, input

In my php file I have the following:

```
  <a class="page-link" href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $_GET['page'] .'&record=' . $record_number . '"">' . $record_number . '</a>
```

This sends a user somewhere based on the current `page` value and `record` value, it is framed in a pagination type situation, so it goes to the next record, it works, its fine.

I also have a text input box, the idea is that a user can type a number and press enter and if that record exists the user goes to that record. If for instance the user chooses record 23, the code would be like this:

```
  <a class="page-link" href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $_GET['page'] .'&record=23"">23</a>
```

So far so good, obviously I'll add in an `if ($record_number >= $max_record)` for good measure.

Now the question, I would like the users to be able to enter a value into an input box, press enter and follow the hyperlink, how is this achieved?

```
<input type="text" style="width:200px;" class="form-control float" id="defaultFormControlInput" placeholder="Go to record" aria-describedby="defaultFormControlHelp">
```

--- UPDATE ---

The below is the 'enter' function so the event listener knows when the enter key is pressed. Given @imvain2's answer below a 'Go' hyper link is displayed and when the link is clicked it functions as required. However, I would like to bypass the link creation so that when 'enter' is pressed then the link is followed without the need for creating a hyperlink first.

```
document.querySelector('#input').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      // code for enter
      
      let url = "?page=artefact&record=" + e.target.value;
      goLINK.classList.toggle("active");
      goLINK.href = url;

    }
});
```

Comment: You could also just wrap it in an HTML form with a `get` `method` and the `action` either set to the direct page or the "lookup" page. I think most browsers natively submit forms on enter these days. Not 100% certain on mobile devices, I guess, although that's also why that paradigm isn't always the best.

Comment: _"However, I would like to bypass the link creation so that when 'enter' is pressed then the link is followed without the need for creating a hyperlink first."_ - `location.href = 'the_new_url';`

Comment: I solved this using: `window.location = "?page=artefact&record=" + e.target.value;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript.

I'm using **URLSearchParams** to get the query string parameter for page. Then in an keyup event I'm looking for the enter button and putting together the URL and adding it an anchor and displaying that anchor by toggling a class called active

```js
let input = document.querySelector("#defaultFormControlInput");
let goLINK = document.querySelector(".goLINK");


const params = new Proxy(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search), {
  get: (searchParams, prop) => searchParams.get(prop),
});

input.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
     let url = "?page=" + (params.page || "1") + "&record=" + e.target.value;
     goLINK.classList.toggle("active");
     goLINK.href = url;
  }
});
```

```css
.goLINK{display:none;}
.goLINK.active{display:block;}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="width:200px;" class="form-control float" id="defaultFormControlInput" placeholder="Go to record" aria-describedby="defaultFormControlHelp">
<a class="goLINK" href="">Go</a>
```

Comment: nearly, I think, but the href is empty, surely that needs to get the `&record=<number from input goes here>`

Comment: @SpatialDigger it is doing that. + e.target.value is getting the value from input. Have you tested it?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`

Comment: It looks like keycode is depreciated so I've replaced that with e.key, but the same error persist pointing to `addEventListener("keyup",function(e){`